# Next.js getServerSideProps() doesn't have access to cookies on first render after redirect but available on refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

in my Next.js app I'm serving cookies from my server-side api:

```js
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', AJWT)
res.redirect(302, '/')
```

in my `index.js` file I'm trying to get the cookie before the page is rendered:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    let cookies = context.req.headers.cookie

    if (typeof cookies !== 'string') {
        return {
            props: { auth: false },
        }
    } else {
        const { AJWT } = cookie.parse(cookies)

        return {
            props: { auth: AJWT ? true : false },
        }
    }
}
```

on the first render after the redirect, cookies are not available but when I refresh they are successfully caught.

Is there a way to make the cookies available on the first render?

**EDIT: and yes the cookie is available on my devtools when I'm first redirected.**

Answer (score 0):

look at cookie`s path. I had the same problem and it was because my cookies were defined just to one page.

```
setCookie(undefined, 'leapy', accessToken, {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1, // 60 minutes
  path: '/',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but a possible cause to this could be that you have set `same-site: "strict"` in the cookie policy. Try `same-site: "lax"` instead. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17612#discussioncomment-4904509